# What does "not abandon" mean in Acts 2:27?

Tags: acts

Acts 2:27 "For you will not abandon my soul to Hades, or let your  Holy One see corruption". ESV

Commenting on this verse Ellicott says that Jesus went "to Hades to carry on the redemptive work which had begun on earth". From this verse Ellicott believed that Jesus went to Hades.

Does Jesus' soul not being abandoned in Hades prove that He went there at all? Even a short time of abandonment would still be abandonment. Or did the Father stay with Him?

If 1 Peter 3:18-22 means that it was Christ's spirit "in which he went" and proclaimed through Noah to those who later died and went to hell, then this would not be a description of Jesus going to Hades after the cross.

Psalm 139:8 "If I make my bed in hell, behold, you are there". Jesus being preeminent in everything [Col 1:18] including Hades, is, I think, not a comment on his not being abandoned there. i.e. In this verse He is present as prison master not as one abandoned there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What does “not abandon” mean in Acts 2:27?**

Acts 2:27 "For you will not abandon my soul to Hades, or let your Holy One see corruption". ESV

Before answering the question it is necessary to clarify the meaning of the words  "soul" and  "Hades

**The Soul, what is it ?**

The word soul is translated from the Greek word " psy-chēn - ψυχὴν "  refers to the person , it is not something immaterial, intangible or immortal that leaves the body on death. Below are some of the many verse, which show that the soul dies. The Bible texts below help us understand the meaning of the word soul as used by the Bible writers.

**Luke 12:20  (NASB)**

> 20 But God said to him, ‘You fool! This very night ***your soul*** is
> required of you; and now who will own what you have prepared?’

L**uke 12:20  (NET Bible)**

> 20 But God said to him, ‘You fool! This very night ***your life*** will be
> demanded back from[b] you, but who will get what you have prepared for
> yourself?’[c]
>
> Matthew 10:28 "And be not afraid of those killing the body, and are
> not able to kill the soul, ***but fear rather Him who is able both soul
> and body to destroy in gehenna".(YLT).***

Acts 3:23 (NASB)

23 And it will be that ***every soul*** that does not heed that prophet shall be utterly destroyed from among the people.

Acts 3:23  (NET Bible)

23 ***Every person*** who does not obey that prophet will be destroyed and thus removed[b] from the people.

**CAN A SOUL DIE?**

Leviticus 24:17-18 (YLT)

> 17 "And when a man smiteth any soul of man, he is certainly put to
> death.18 `And he who smiteth a beast repayeth it, body for body."

**Hades:**

The Bible uses the word "hades and its Hebrew equivalent  "Sheol  about 70 times , some translators use the words "grave", "hell " or "pit"

The Bible teaching of the resurrection helps us to gain further insight into the meaning of “Sheol” and “Hades.” God’s Word associates Sheol and Hades with the sort of death from which there will be a resurrection.* (Job 14:13; Acts 2:31; Revelation 20:13)

Revelation 20:13 NASB

> 13 And the sea gave up the dead who were in it, and Death and Hades
> gave up the dead who were in them; and they were judged, each one of
> them according to their deeds.

**Not abandon (Acts 2:27) means: not left in the grave but resurrected.**

Since Hades refers to the common grave of mankind, Jesus entered within “the gates of Hades” when buried by Joseph of Arimathea. On Pentecost of 33 C.E., Peter said of Christ: “Neither was he forsaken in Hades nor did his flesh see corruption. This Jesus God resurrected, of which fact we are all witnesses.” (Acts  2:25-27, 29-32; Psalm  16:10) Whereas “the gates of Hades” (Matthew 16:18) were still holding David within their domain in Peter’s day (Acts  2:29), they had swung open for Christ Jesus when his Father resurrected him out of Hades. Thereafter, through the power of the resurrection given him (John 5:21-30), Jesus is the Holder of “the keys of death and of Hades.”​—Re 1:17, 18.

Answer (score 1):

"Even a short time of abandonment would still be abandonment."

The Greek word egkataleipó (G1459) carries a meaning stronger than that.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> 1. to abandon, desert ... to leave in straits, leave **helpless** ...
> 2. to leave behind among, to leave surviving

Did the Father stay with Him?

I believe so. The Father did not leave His Son helpless in Hades.

Does Jesus' soul not being abandoned in Hades prove that He went there?

It is one support for that but by itself, not sufficient as proof. The context has to do with bodily decay, not visiting Hades.

What does “not abandon” mean in Acts 2:27?

It means not leaving him completely helpless, no more and no less.